# Reassign / Update Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried searching all over the web but could only find how to reassign cell values.

A little background for my code:

The input sheet contains data in columns A through U, but columns R and S are purposefully empty. I need to set & sort the Data Range from columns A through Q ONLY, and the number of rows may change every time I run the code (so the row index needs to be dynamic). When I run my code, the variable does not update, and I don't get any errors. Why is the code not updating my variable for input data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
function SortUpdate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var inputData = input.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = inputData.getNumRows();
  inputData = input.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 17);
  for(var i = 9; i<=(15);i++){
     inputData.sort({column: i, ascending: false});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So far you have assigned two different ranges to inputData but you have not collected any data.  Take a look at the range.getValues() function [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

```
function SortUpdate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var inputData = input.getDataRange();//This returns a range not data
  var lastRow = inputData.getNumRows();
  inputData = input.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 17);//The inputData variable has received two assignments which one do you want?  Both are ranges and do not have any data.
  for(var i = 9; i<=(15);i++){
     inputData.sort({column: i, ascending: false});
  }
}
```

It would be helpful to see some of your data.

I looked at the range.sort command and some of the examples and I'm wondering if you don't think that it was intended to be used like this:

```
inputData.sort([{column: 9 ascending: false},{column: 10, ascending: false},{column: 11, ascending: false},{column: 12 , ascending: false},{column: 13, ascending: false},{column: 14, ascending: false},{column: 15, ascending: false}]);
```

I put the command into the function like below.  You won't be able to get this to run because I'm using some of my own utilities to store a global variable in an array in a file so that I can toggle the ascending argument between true and false every time I run it. But this is what it looks like and it definitely is sorting columns A through Q not including the header row.

```
function SortUpdate() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var input = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var inputData = input.getDataRange();//This returns a range not data
  var lastRow = inputData.getNumRows();
  inputData = input.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 17);//The inputData variable has received two assignments which one do you want?
  var dirA=myUtilities.getArrayByName('Params');
  inputData.sort([{column: 9, ascending: dirA.state=='true'},{column: 10, ascending: dirA.state=='true'},{column: 11, ascending: dirA.state=='true'},{column: 12 , ascending: dirA.state=='true'},{column: 13, ascending: dirA.state=='true'},{column: 14, ascending: dirA.state=='true'},{column: 15, ascending: dirA.state=='true'}]);
  dirA['state'] = (dirA['state']=='true')?false:true;
  myUtilities.saveArray('Params', 'DICT', dirA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper!
I want these to be ranges, not values. Basically, I'm trying to say, "Of all  the data present in this sheet, ONLY manipulate the values in columns A through Q." But because .getRange() needs an end row, I had to first find where that end row is located. Then once I've located that end row, I can reassign inputData with the updated range. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it seems like a reasonable way to go.  Have you got your sorting working yet?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the sheet.getDataRange() and sheet.getNumRows(), you can use the sheet.getLastRow() method, who will return the value of the last row use on the sheet. More about the getLastRow method : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()

For the sort method part, you can use the code write by Cooper which is working, or send us a exemple of what kind of sort method you want.